# Get all nodes related to the nodes in a path in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, nodes

I have a database of movies and months they are released in. Movies are connected to months by `[:released]`. Each month is connected to the other by `[:NEXT]`.

The structure looks like this:

```
1->2->3->4..->12->1->2->..
```

as in a time tree

```
(movie{title:'Matrix'})-[:released]->(month)
```

[image]

Now I have the path of all those months in variable `p`. `Nodes(p)` returns all the months.

I want to now return all the movies associated with each month in `p`. Can some one please help me with that?

[EDITED to include details from @Shiva]

Actually, the query goes like this:

```
match
  startPath=(root)-[:HAS_Year]->(year1:Year{year:1950})-[:HAS_MONTH]->(startLeaf:M‌​onth{month:1}),
  endPath = (root)-[:HAS_Year]->(year2:Year{year:1951})-[:HAS_MONTH]->(endLeaf:Month{month:1‌​2}),
  p=(startLeaf)-[:NEXT*0..]->(endLeaf)
```

Finally I have the path "p" and now I want to retrieve all the movie nodes associated to the month nodes in the path. I am not quite sure how to fetch them I am actually trying to query on a time tree model and check on any difference in execution time and so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATED]

This should work for you:

```
MATCH
  (root)-[:HAS_Year]->(:Year {year:1950})-[:HAS_MONTH]->(start:Month {month:1}),
  (root)-[:HAS_Year]->(:Year {year:1951})-[:HAS_MONTH]->(end:Month {month:12}),
  p=(start)-[:NEXT*0..]->(end)
WITH NODES(p) AS months
UNWIND months AS month
OPTIONAL MATCH (month)<-[:released]-(movie)
RETURN month, COLLECT(movie) AS movies;
```

### Alternate solution if data model can be altered

As @NicoleWhite suggested, there is simpler solution. If all `Month` nodes contained a `timestamp` property that combined the year and date info like this:
"2015-01", then the query could be simply this:

```
MATCH (movie:Movie)-[:released]->(month:Month)
WHERE month.timestamp >= "1950-01" AND month.timestamp <= "1951-12"
RETURN month, COLLECT(movie) AS movies
ORDER BY month.timestamp;
```

And if you create an index on timestamp:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Month(timestamp);
```

then you can make the query more efficient (but you currently have to tell Cypher to use the index):

```
MATCH (movie:Movie)-[:released]->(month:Month)
USING INDEX month:Month(timestamp)
WHERE month.timestamp >= "1950-01" AND month.timestamp <= "1951-12"
RETURN month, COLLECT(movie) AS movies
ORDER BY month.timestamp;
```

Comment: There's no point bothering with the linked list if you're getting all months. You can just do `MATCH (movie:Movie)-[:RELEASED]->(month:Month) RETURN month, COLLECT(movie) AS movies;`

Comment: Great point. I wanted to return the results in month order, but it was not clear if the `Month` nodes have a usable timestamp for ordering the nodes. But I will update my answer with you excellent suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: The convention is to have a `month` property with the integer of the month and an `id` property with the year-month, e.g. "2015-01" for ordering.

Comment: Actually, the query goes like this:
 
match startPath=(root)-[:HAS_Year]->(year1:Year{year:1950})-[:HAS_MONTH]->(startLeaf:Month{month:1}),

endPath = (root)-[:HAS_Year]->(year2:Year{year:1951})-[:HAS_MONTH]->(endLeaf:Month{month:12}),

p=(startLeaf)-[:NEXT*0..]->(endLeaf)


Finally I have the path "p" and now I want to retrieve all the movie nodes associated to the month nodes in the path. I am not quite sure how to fetch them

I am actually trying to query on a time tree model and check on any difference in execution time and so, I cannot actually use the above query by @cybersam here.

Comment: OK, see my updated answer. I have also updated the question to include your details.

Comment: Thanks a lot @cybersam. That worked!! 
Also many thanks for formatting my question.

Comment: I will also try the alternate approach as suggested by @NicoleWhite but I am just wondering if the time stamp is a string, then will it be able to do a correct time ordering of events within the given range and return them?

Comment: If you format the timestamp in the way suggested, then comparisons and sorts will work as intended.